# Place marker on click google maps javascript api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have coded a google map in JS Apis.

What I'm trying to achieve is that wherever the user clicks, it places the marker there and outputs its Lat and Lng.

What I have achieved is wherever I click, it outputs the Lat and Lng without dragging the marker there.

Here the Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/sarthakbatra1991/87v0obb4/#&togetherjs=3aTj11AiwO

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {


        document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
        document.getElementById("long").value = event.latLng.lng();
        marker.setPosition(lat, lng);
        marker.setMap(map);

    });
```

Please look at it and help me out here.

Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`lat` and `lng` are not defined in the click listener.  This should work:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
  document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
  document.getElementById("long").value = event.latLng.lng();
  marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87v0obb4/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.713956, -74.006653);

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    draggable: true,
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: "Your location"
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(event) {
    document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById("long").value = event.latLng.lng();
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    document.getElementById("lat").value = event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById("long").value = event.latLng.lng();
    marker.setPosition(event.latLng);
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize());
```

```css
<style> html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%
}
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
Lat:
<input id="lat" name="lat" val="40.713956" />Long:
<input id="long" name="long" val="74.006653" />
<br />
<br />
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 250px;"></div>
```