# Google Maps - click and fill form

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jinja2

I was unclear when I asked my question earlier. I'll try rewording it and give more examples.

I have a google map -

```
<script>
              var map;
          function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: {lat: 39.8333333, lng: -98.585522},
              zoom: 3

            });
          }
        </script>
```

What I want to do is be able to click on the map and have it fill a form that is generated by Jinja2

```
  <form method=post action="/add_spot/">
    <dl>
      {{render_field(form.lat)}}
      {{render_field(form.lng)}}
    </dl>
    <p><input type=submit value=Submit></p>
  </form>
```

I understand that you should use

`window.google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
// do stuff
});`

or something similar. However, I am unsure of how to combine the map JS and the clicker JS and/or what goes into the "do stuff" line. Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

NOTE* The possible duplicate in the comments didn't help me much because it involves just placing the marker and doesn't involve putting the coordinates in the form boxes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Place marker on click google maps javascript api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053426/place-marker-on-click-google-maps-javascript-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as (assuming `map` is your map)

```
  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    // e.latLng has the lat/long of the click - fill in your form in this callback
  });
```

Comment: You are right, I figured out how to implement it now, so thanks.