# Set marker with click on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, click

How could I let the user set markers with a click on the map?
In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) only dragging of markers is mentioned.

Is there a built-in way or do I have to listen for the click event manually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Place marker on click google maps javascript api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35053426/place-marker-on-click-google-maps-javascript-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach a click listener to the map:

`google.maps.event.addListener(MAPOBJECT, 'click', function(event) {});`

Use it like so:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(MAPOBJECT, 'click', function(event) {
    var x = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: MAPOBJECT
    });
});
```

WHERE MAPOBJECT would be something like:

```
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('sampleId'), {
            zoom: 5,
            center: {lat: 28.7041, lng: 78.9629}
        });
```